# Increasing the difficulty/cost of manipulating an on-chain PRNG?

Tags: solidity, randomness

well, from what I understand since everything on-chain is deterministic so theoretically there's no way of having a real cryptograhically secure random number generator that cannot be manipulated by the miners. However, aside from using off-chain random data sources from Oracles, I wonder if there are some ways to surely increase the difficulty/cost of manipulating an on-chain PRNG?

For example, the most basic and naive on-chain PRNG is to use blockhash of a past block (I'm not talking about knowing the result of the PRNG beforehand, but to really manipulate the result, so I'm not using future blockhash as example here)

```
rand = uint256(blockhash(block.number - 1))
```

So the miner who mined the previous block will be able to manipulate the value of rand.

Now if someone do something like

```
rand = uint256(blockhash(block.number - 1)) ^ uint256(blockhash(block.number - 2))
```

From what I understand it actually doesn't increase the difficulty of manipulating the value of rand, as the miner of the previous block already knows the blockhash before it, so it still only takes the miner to mine the previous block to manipulate the result.

So doing things like

```
rand = uint256(blockhash(block.number - 1)) ^ uint256(blockhash(block.number - 2)) ^ uint256(blockhash(block.number - 3)) ^ ...
```

are practically useless since it still only takes the miner to mine the previous block to manipulate the result.

And as such, using future blockhashes are also useless in this case since it still only takes one miner to mine a deciding block to manipulate the result.

So is there anyway to actually increase the difficulty for a miner to manipulate an on-chain PRNG (for example, a miner has to mine two or three specific blocks to manipuate the result instead of just one block), or is it actually impossible by theory (ie. it always only takes a miner to mine one block to be able to manipulate the result of a purely on-chain PRNG without off-chain data input)?